# Remover último item da tabela e repor um novo item acima do primeiro

Tags: php, mysql

Como eu faria para remover o último item de uma tabela selecionando os quatro recentes.

Ex:

```
+-----------------+--------+
+------ ITEM -----+-VALOR--+
+--------------------------+

1: FulanoA        + está online
2: FulanoA        + está ausente
3: FulanoB        + se cadastrou
4: FulanoC        + não está
```

com base nessa mini tabela eu queria adicionar um item dela, removendo o último e adicionando mais um.

Ex:

```
5: FulanoZ       + entrou
```

e onde se encontra o FulanoC será removido e inserido acima do FulanoA.

Queria utilizar códigos simples e/ou simplificados.

Comment: Você pode fazer uma tabela auxiliar, que registra os acessos e ordena por ordem de acesso.

Comment: Estás a dizer que `FulanoA` passaria a posição `2`, `FulanoB` passaria a posição `3` e assim por diante ?

Comment: sim! sempre retornado ex: 3 vira o 2, o 2 vira 1 etc...

Comment: Mas desse jeito não seria meio trabalhoso ? Qual é o propósito da tabela afinal ?

Comment: Você pode ordernar pelo campo que você quer  primeiro:

`ORDER BY FIELD(status, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Pois não vejo sentido em querer remover um e colocar outro no lugar. Qual sua ideia?

Comment: A organização dos registros na lista é feita pela hora/min em que acontecem, correto? tipo, quanto mais no topo, mas recente é ação, certo?

Comment: Mas se for de tipo ordenado em ordem ascendente ao tempo de entrada, basta atualizar o campo responsável pelo registro do tempo sempre que o usuário entrar, e daí a ordem do display, seria feita durante a saída ou processamento dos dados na tabela, e não permanentemente pelo _SQL_. Porque este tipo de sistema que estás a pedir é mais viável para _CMS_ e coisas do gênero. Por isso repito a pergunta. _Qual é o teu principal objetivo nessa estrutura ?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melhor forma de criar uma dinâmica desta é através de um controle de banco de dados, onde a cada alteração de status de usuário seria registrado o status, qual usuário pertence e a data da alteração.

Um exemplo de schema de banco:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_status` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
 `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
 `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Pronto, montamos o banco. Neste banco será registrado cada alteração de status de usuário, junto com a data que será preenchida automaticamente com `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

> Lembrando que no ambiente da sua aplicação será preciso criar uma chave estrangeira para o `ID` do usuário. Referenciando o registro a ele.

A cada movimentação de status na sua aplicação você irá gerar uma query de insert para esta tabela:

```
INSERT INTO `user_status` (`name`, `status`) VALUES ('FulanoA', 'está online')
```

Desta forma será registrado alteração de status do `FulanoA` para `está online`.

Para recuperar estes status é só rodar uma query nesta tabela, buscando as últimas movimentações de status ordernando pelo campo `created_at`;

```
SELECT `us`.`name`, `us`.`status` FROM `user_status` us us ORDER BY `us`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Esta query irá retornar os últimos 4 registros ordenado pela data de alteração, será saída da forma que deseja.

A cada nova alteração de status o último registro irá sair da tabela e um novo irá entrar no começo dela, mesmo joguinho que demonstrou no exemplo com `FulanoZ`.

#### Considerações

Vou fazer algumas considerações levando em consideração esta modelagem.

#### Banco de dados

É um pouco custoso para performance esses hit's constantes no banco, a cada alteração você registrar e mostrar, imagine isso em grande escala. [Custo de I/O](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/335/io_-_parte_1_-_o_que_e) será alto para sua aplicação. Imagine isso em serviço on-demand?

**Então qual melhor saída?**

Análise qual necessidade dessa interação, para qual intuito e valor desta funcionalidade x custo dela.

É preciso analisar e ver se a demanda vale a pena o custo de performance, apenas para mostrar histórico de movimentação de status dos usuários.

### Alternativas

Trabalhar com estes registros em um banco não é bem o recomendado, porém caso deseja utilizar um banco para estas movimentações recomendo o `noSQL` que terá o custo menor para estas consultas frequentes.

Também temos o [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis)

> Redis é um banco de dados NoSQL que trabalha com a ideia de chave valor. A chave, assim como seu valor podem ser quase qualquer coisa, como um Hash no Ruby ou um Map no Java . Sendo um jeito muito fácil de guardar dados como o cache do usuário, ou filas de tarefas.

Que é o mais aconselhável para esta tarefa, que justamente é `noSQL`.

Bom, eu fico devendo um pouco mais de código, já que esta dúvida não é muito referente a **como fazer** e sim **como funciona**. Todas alternativas abordadas aqui podem ser feitas em diversas linguagens, depende da analise do seu projeto e demanda.

Recomendo estudar as alternativas colocadas aqui, pois isto é realmente algo que comerá sua performance com farinha rsrs se não bem modelada.

Bom, espero que tenha esclarecido algo.

Answer (score 1):

O melhor a fazer é criar uma coluna 'dataCadastro' e excluir co a SQL Delete form tabela where dataCadastro = min( dataCadastro )

Comment: Será que isso seria válido? Apenas executo 
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'usuarios' LIMIT 0,10 ORDER BY id DESC")`

Comment: O problema é que o ORDER BY vai ordernar pelo que??? Você pode acabar excluíndo um item mais recente só porque na ordem alfabética ele vem por último.